# Modeling a picture frame

Tags: modeling, normals, sculpting

I'm doing a VR Museum and I need to model some painting frames (picture for reference). I know how to make the basic structure of the frame, but the organic details are what's really bothering me. Is there any trick to do this kind of object or is my best bet sculpting, or something related to normal maps.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I hope someone has a better Idea than what I posted because it is a pain for such a "simple" object. At least for someone like me who can't sculpt

Comment: Please dónde duplicate your posts. You had asked that already. If you are not getting answers please edit your original post ducumwnting what you have tried that isn't working.

Comment: Ty HenrikD. And cegaton sorry for the repost

Comment: I hesitate to suggest watching videos like [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pBOutY0PAzc&t=261s).. that would just be cruel...

Comment: Ty kind stranger

Answer (score 1):

You could also try geometric modelling, but if you know how to sculpt that is also my best bet. If you have a Displacement Texture you can make a base mesh with the Displace Modifier to get a first approximation. Either way if you are modeling for VR Realtime Rendering you should make a remeshed version for the final version.